# Implement Login/Logout in MVC with 3-Tier architecture using Entity Framework and DI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, 3-tier, ninject.web.mvc, data-layers

I want to implement Login/Logout service in ASP.NET MVC using 3-Tier architecture. I also want to use Entity Framework and dependency injection pattern, like NInject (for example).

Can somebody advise some articles, where I can see some examples or tutorials? It looks like the most articles in internet are for WebForms...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/crud-using-the-repository-pattern-in-mvc/
The article is a good example for basic understanding of EF, DI and 3-Tier architecture in MVC.

Comment: Kindly, @Dimitri do up-vote and accept any comment/answer which you find useful.